# Deleted user's name underlines on hover as though it were a clickable link

Tags: bug, comments, design, deleted-accounts

Consider the following comment on Math.SE: [How to distinguish between walking on a sphere and walking on a torus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854380/how-to-distinguish-walking-on-a-sphere-or-on-a-torus/854783#comment1762842_854394)

[image]

In the image, I have hovered over "user21467". This user's account is deleted (as you can see by the post on which this comment is made), but the user's name still gets underlined. The mouse cursor remains `text` rather than switching to `pointer`.

The issue is that names of deleted users are in `span.comment-user` elements while names of non-deleted users are in `a.comment-user` elements, and `all.css` contains the following (unminified):

```
.post-text a:hover, .comment-copy a:hover, .comment-user:hover {
    color: #1f82a7;
    text-decoration: underline
}
```

I feel like this used to not happen, but I could be mistaken.

Posted on Meta.SE rather than a child meta because this probably happens on any site where links are underlined on hover.

Comment: The profile would link here, so they're definitely gone: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/21467

Comment: @qwer Your link is to Super User, not Programmers.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that this behavior is specific to Mathematics. There are 7 sites where the link to a comment author's profile is underlined on hover:

- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)
- [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)
- [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/)
- [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/)
- [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search)
- [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

On all of them, except Mathematics, the link loses its color and decoration if the user is deleted ([example found by qwer](https://superuser.com/questions/205770/is-there-any-way-to-properly-display-negative-time-spans-in-excel#comment208686_205771)). On Mathematics it keeps both.

Comment: Just curious, you found this before or after starting the bounty?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, the logs show they were posted at the same time.

Comment: It seems that if the reported behavior is specific to Mathematics, it should be migrated, not answered.

Comment: @Gnemlock no, the bounty was started at 18:47 and the answer was posted at 19:32 I just checked now, so looks like zaq got what he was looking for in those 45 minutes. Too bad the bounty went to waste